# gnuplot how to merge two every commands in one line

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with 1200 rows. I am trying to use *every* command which will plot any chunk of data (for example from 6th to 800th data but every 5 points. I know how to exploit *every* to select first 1000 data (but not any chunk) and *every* 5 points separately. Is there any way to do that in an one liner?

`Plot "file.dat" every ::::1000 every 5 u 1:4` fails to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `help every` for an explanation of the empty sites in your `every ::::1000` command:

```
Syntax:
   plot 'file' every {<point_incr>}
                       {:{<block_incr>}
                         {:{<start_point>}
                           {:{<start_block>}
                             {:{<end_point>}
                               {:<end_block>}}}}}
```

In your case you need only the *point* parameters, *block* marks distinct parts of a data file which are separated by one newline.

So you plot command to select every 5th point between the 6th and 800th row is:

```
plot 'datafile.dat' every 5::6::800 using 1:4
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to plot every fifth point from only the first 1000 points, I do not think there is a (reasonably simple) way to do that in pure gnuplot.  One option is to use an external command to do simple processing on your data file:

```
plot '< head -n 1000 datafile.dat' every 5
```

(For details on what that syntax does, type `help plot special` in gnuplot, or search for 'popen' in the gnuplot docs.)

Comment: SO for any chunk from the entire series how could I possibly plot it? Thanks for the lead for plot special